# How can I choose to unrar with the default application?

Tags: software, rar

I recently installed unrar for Mac Os X but i found it useless sometimes and bug-full.
So i uninstalled unrar. Now if i open a .rar file, another application (VLC) open it.
But i want the default unrar application to manage .rar files. How can i do that? If i select the "Open with" options and i look for that application in the applications folder i cant find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no default application to handle .rar file on Mac OS X.

You might want to try [**The Unarchiver**](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html). It can open many format besides *rar* files.

Then once you installed it, open its preferences and select all the file format you want him to manage.

[image: unarchiver]

Comment: +agreed... the unarchiver works better than the default decompression utility anyway, and Loic is right, the default will not work with .rar files.

Comment: the unarchiver it is. Handles lot's of file formats.